# Exploding every character except numbers with PHP

Tags: php, numbers, explode

I have an URL which I am trying to explode evreything out of it and get only the numbers in it... it looks something like that: www.url.com/blalb/5435/blabla

The url is different all the time, so I need to explode everything else but the numbers.
It has to be with PHP.

Comment: do you want a preg_match with the number?

Comment: I don't mind, and if there's no number at all in the URL i'd like that the user will see an error.

Comment: `if(!preg_match("#[0-9]#", $url))` ...?

Comment: yeah that's fine, but still I need to see the replace code, so I will be able to use the numbers as variables.

Comment: read about preg_match()'s third parameter: http://php.net/preg_match

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$url;                  #this contains your url string
$matches = array();    #this will contain the matched numbers

if(preg_match_all('/\d+/', $url, $matches)) {
    $numbers = implode('', $matches[0]);
    echo "numbers in string: $numbers";
}
```

This uses a regular expression with `preg_match_all` to match ALL groups of digits in the string, putting each group into the `$matches[0]` array. Then you can simply `implode` this array of digit groups into a string.

For example, if `$url` contained `'www.url.com/blalb/5435/blabla/0913'`, the output would be `numbers in string: 54350913`.

If you just want to match the *first* group of digits in the URL, use `preg_match` instead of `preg_match_all`:

```
if(preg_match('/\d+/', $url, $matches)) {
    $numbers = implode('', $matches);
    echo "numbers in string: $numbers";
}
```

If you want to match a specific group of digits in a string (besides the first), you'll need a more complex regex.